# Java Process - wait for process to exit

Tags: java

i was trying to use a python script in my java program. The python, if run outside java, starts, then waits for an event, when the event occurs, does something, prints the result and exits.

When i try to use it in Java, it does not wait for the event, but exits immediately with an empty response. How can i wait for the script to quit, and so hang the java program till it exits?

this is the method i'm testing

```
public static String readRFID() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/Read.py");
        Process p = pb.start();

         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
               p.getInputStream()));

         p.waitFor();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while(br.readLine() != null) {
                sb.append(br.readLine());
            }
           return sb.toString();

    }
```

Comment: waitFor should probably be *after* the loop

Comment: Does the Python script read from standard input? When run from a Java app, the script's standard input is not what it is when run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

- `waitFor()` should *definitely* be after the read loop;
- you need to close the process's `stdin`; and
- you need to consume all of both its `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: i put waitFor() after the loop (silly mistake...) but i can't understand what you mean with the other 2 points...

Comment: Check the API. It's pretty obvious. You're already consuming `stdout`.